# How to perform case-sensitive query-replace?

Tags: query-replace, case-folding

When I do `M-x query-replace` to replace all occurrences of `v` by `w`,  then it also matches `V` (uppercase `V`). How to force emacs to only find lowercase `v` ?

Comment: "Case-insensitive" is the default behavior, where case doesn't matter in the search. If you want to only match one case, it's "case-sensitive" that you want. (I might miss something too, feel free to rollback the edit if needed)

Comment: @T.Verron I am convinced now, you are right.

Comment: There's a clever way of doing this in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61410/2246).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(customize-set-variable case-fold-search  nil)
```

Or bind that variable (option) in your own command that is otherwise just a wrapper around `query-replace`.  This has the advantage that it doesn't change the variable value for general use, outside of query-replacing.

See also variable `case-replace`, which controls case for the replacement text.

See also `C-h f query-replace`, where it says, for example:

> Matching is independent of case if `case-fold-search` is non-nil and
> FROM-STRING has no uppercase letters.  Replacement transfers the case
> pattern of the old text to the new text, if `case-replace` and
> `case-fold-search` are non-nil and FROM-STRING has no uppercase

See also the comments below, and Emacs bug #[20687](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20687), which show how you can patch `perform-replace` to let you toggle case folding during `query-replace`.

---

Note too that the existing code for `perform-replace` binds `case-fold-search` in this way (note the variables on which it depends):

```
(case-fold-search  (if (and case-fold-search search-upper-case)
                       (isearch-no-upper-case-p from-string regexp-flag)
                     case-fold-search))
```

Comment: It would have been nice to change `case-fold-search` on the fly as we can do during `isearch` using the `M-c` binding. But unfortunately `query-replace` does have have its mode map.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Normally, it would be as simple as  adding a key binding for that to `query-replace-map`: `(defun toggle-case () (interactive) (setq case-fold-search (not case-fold-search)))` and `(define-key query-replace-map "C" 'toggle-case)`. But the handling of keys in that map is hard-coded in `perform-replace`. You might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to get the `perform-replace` code to be more open-ended, so keys can be added to the map. It should at least have a fallback clause that just invokes the cmd bound to the key.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't find `query-replace-map` before.

Comment: I've filed that bug report now (#[20687](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20687)). The solution is in that bug report: Just modify `perform-replace` to add an additional `cond` clause that invokes the key you've defined in `query-replace-map`. Put the new clause just before the catch-all `t` clause. This is the new clause: `(def (call-interactively def))`. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: `(customize-set-variable case-fold-search  nil)` gives the error `customize-set-variable: Attempt to set a constant symbol: nil`. Also I  tried both `(setq  case-fold-search  nil)` and `(setq  case-replace  nil)`but the query still match the uppercase V.

Comment: @Name `case-fold-search` is a buffer-local variable. What do you see when you do `C-h v case-fold-search` in the buffer where you are doing the `query-replace`?

Comment: Your above comment about defining `(defun toggle-case () (interactive) (setq case-fold-search (not case-fold-search)))` solved my problem. When I execute `toggle-case` then I can use case-insensitive query-replace.

Comment: Thanks **@Drew**! I got a wonderfully [working solution](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/commit/6636510769fc5f115ea399d906f30ad2395638e4) to toggle the case fold during query-replace. In addition to your suggested patch, I added few more touches to a nice stable solution: [touch-1](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6636510769fc5f115ea399d906f30ad2395638e4/setup-files/setup-search.el#L13-L20), [touch-2](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6636510769fc5f115ea399d906f30ad2395638e4/elisp/patches/replace-patches.el#L231-L237)

Comment: @kaushalmodi: After experimenting, consider sending your code as a patch to the same bug report.

Comment: @Drew There's only one little issue with this solution; the first match will use the default state of the `perform-replace`-internal value of `case-fold-search`. Once that match is found, only then you get a chance to hit that `C` binding to toggle the case. So for that first match, in most of the cases, you would have to hit `n` to move on to the next possible match that would satisfy the intended case fold condition. We need to get an option to toggle the case BEFORE the first match is searched for.. hope I was able to get the point across.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Yes, I know. Not a big deal, IMO. But you are welcome to look for a different solution. IMO, typically a user of this feature will start q-r, realize soon enough if case-folding is not what s?he wants, and toggle it. Often s?he will se multiple hits highlighted and understand immediately, etc.

Comment: So is the solution that @Drew submitted as [#20687](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20687) merged? Don't see it in Emacs 25.1.1, and there hasn't been follow-up in 2 yrs.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: Please consider pinging the bug thread, if you would like progress on this. Maybe some kind soul will take care of it.

Comment: Would be nice to just make it a command modifier, so if I C-u it performs case-sensitive matching.

Comment: Can I achieve this under `find-name-dired` ? @Drew

Comment: @alper: Not sure I understand. Do you mean case sensitivity for matching the file name? That's controlled by the `find` command. You can typically use switch `-iname` instead of `-name`, to get case-insensitive name matching; otherwise it's case-sensitive.

Comment: @DidierA.: `C-h f query-replace` says that a prefix arg has another behavior: *"In interactive use, the prefix arg (non-nil DELIMITED in
non-interactive use), means replace only matches surrounded by
word boundaries.  A negative prefix arg means replace backward."*

Comment: I was using `find-name-dired` to make a query change on the all files, I asked as a new question (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/59246/18414) to be more clear

Comment: now, years later, a patch was actually merged in Emacs 28, but it's unclear to me how it can actually be used, if at all. I tried with `  (defun anarcat/toggle-case ()
    (interactive)
    (setq case-fold-search (not case-fold-search))
    (message "toggled case-fold-search to %s" case-fold-search))
  (define-key query-replace-map (kbd "C") #'anarcat/toggle-case))` and while the (message) call shows the fold-search flipping, it doesn't actually affect the search results. this is really a big inconsistency between query replace and isearch!