# How to query-replace with exact match with the exact given word in case-sensetive manner?

Tags: query-replace, case-folding

I have `HELLOWORLD` string inside my file.

---

My setup:

```
(defun my-find-orgfiles ()
  (interactive)
  (setq toggle-case-fold-search 0)  ; Turn Off Smart Case Sensitivity
  (find-name-dired "~/folder" "*py"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'my-find-orgfiles)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")))
(setq case-fold-search nil)
```

Than, `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then I use `Q` to use `query-replace on the marked files`. And enter `helloword` to replace with `hello`.

---

On the minibuffer I face with following:

`Query replacing helloworld with HELLO: (? for help)`

Than replaces `HELLOWORLD` into `HELLO`.

- Here if replacement occurs I want it to replace into `hello` rather than `HELLO`, since I enter lower case `hello`
- Since  lower case `helloword` does not exist in the file, it shouldn't attempt to replace anything.

---

Note: Adding  `(setq case-fold-search nil)` did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `M-x toggle-case-fold-search` (message is `Case-Insensitive Search disabled globally`) before `Q`.

`toggle-case-fold-search` isn't a standard variable but rather a function.  Perhaps you wanted to set buffer-local variable `case-fold-search` in `my-find-orgfiles`?  Or maybe to call `toggle-case-fold-search`?

Comment: Can I set it in `.emacs` file?

Comment: Yes, you can `(setq case-fold-search nil)` in your .emacs/.init.el

Comment: I did but still I am having the same problem, it did not have any affect @Mark

Comment: Because it's a buffer-local variable, you'll may want `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)`