# How do I search/replace with case sensitive search?

Tags: search, replace, query-replace, case-folding

In emacs I'm using `M-%` to replace occurrences of `b_abcd` (of which there are only a few) with `B_abcd` (of which there are very many). Currently Emacs asks if it's OK to replace at each `B_abcd`, which takes a lot of time to wade through all `B_abcd`s it finds.

How can I make Emacs ask only about replacing `b_abcd` occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind or set `case-fold-search` to `nil`.

`C-h k M-%` tells us:

> **`M-%`** runs the command `query-replace` (found in `global-map`), which is an
> interactive compiled Lisp function in `replace.el`.
>
> It is bound to `M-%`, `<menu-bar> <edit> <replace> <query-replace>`.
>
> `(query-replace FROM-STRING TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END BACKWARD REGION-NONCONTIGUOUS-P)`
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 1.3.
>
> Replace some occurrences of `FROM-STRING` with `TO-STRING`.
>
> As each match is found, the user must type a character saying
> what to do with it.  For directions, type `C-h` at that time.

...

> **Matching is independent of case if both `case-fold-search`
> and `search-upper-case` are non-`nil` and `FROM-STRING` has no
> uppercase letters; if `search-upper-case` is `nil`, then
> whether matching ignores case depends on `case-fold-search`
> regardless of whether there are uppercase letters in `FROM-STRING`.
> Replacement transfers the case pattern of the old text to the
> new text, if both `case-fold-search` and `case-replace` are
> non-`nil` and `FROM-STRING` has no uppercase letters.
> (Transferring the case pattern means that if the old text
> matched is all caps, or capitalized, then its replacement is
> respectively upcased or capitalized.)**

If your string to replace had uppercase letters and you wanted to always respect case then you would set `case-fold-search` to non-`nil` and `search-upper-case` to `nil`. In your case the string to replace has no uppercase letters, so it's sufficient to set `case-fold-search` to non-`nil`.

You can *customize* either or both of these variables (options), to make them have the values you want most often by default.  That way, you will only need to set or bind them occasionally, for your less frequent uses. To customize them, use `M-x customize-option`.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you so much for your quick answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use isearch (`C-s`), turn on case sensitivity (`M-c`) then launch replace (`M-%`) from there.

- `M-c` runs the command `isearch-toggle-case-fold`
- `M-%` runs the command `isearch-query-replace`