# How can I query replace region from top case-sensitively?

Tags: replace, case-folding

I am using following [answer to search and replace a word in the entire buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50624/18414):

> ````lisp
> (defun query-replace-region-or-from-top ()   
>   (interactive)  
>   (progn
>     (let ((orig-point (point)))
>       (if (use-region-p)
>           (call-interactively 'query-replace)
>         (save-excursion
>           (goto-char (point-min))
>           (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
>       (message "Back to old point.")
>       (goto-char orig-point)))) 
>
> (global-set-key "\C-x\C-r"  'query-replace-region-or-from-top)```
> ````

---

When I apply `query-replace-region-or-from-top`, for example `emacs` into `emacs_world` it also changes `EMACS` into `EMACS_WORLD`.

How can I make `query-replace-region-or-from-top` case-sensitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search/replace with case sensitive search?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61408/how-do-i-search-replace-with-case-sensitive-search)

Comment: @Drew yes sir , NickD's answer also helps how can I use it

Comment: The question seems to be a duplicate of that question, in which case it should be deleted.

Comment: Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346107/emacs-case-sensitive-replace-string/5346418#5346418 // small example is helpful to understand how can I use it under the `defun` function like using `(let ((case-fold-search nil))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let-bind `case-fold-search` to nil:

```el
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top ()   
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))  
    (progn
      ...
      (goto-char orig-point)))))
```

See the doc string for `case-fold-search` with `C-h v case-fold-search`:

> case-fold-search is a variable defined in ‘src/buffer.c’.
>
> Its value is t
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
> You can customize this variable.
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 18.
>
> Non-nil if searches and matches should ignore case.